# How can two different generations of one family be a half sibling to an outsider?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

My full paternal uncle and I enough cM with an outsider to both be listed as half siblings to an unknown male.  My uncle shares more cM with that unknown male than I do (a female).

Both my uncle and I are listed as half siblings to this person.  I don't understand how two different generations of known lineage can be half siblings with with the same person.

Here are the numbers:

Uncle and "*the male outsider*"
26% shared DNA | 1,809 cM across 41 segments
Unweighted shared DNA: **1,809 cM**
Longest segment: 125 cM
100% 1/2 sibling

Me  and  *the "male outsider"*
Shared DNA: 1,655 cM across 28 segments
Unweighted shared DNA: **1,655 cM**
Longest segment: 165 cM
100% 1/2 sibling.

My Uncle and I
Shared DNA: 1,599 cM across 41 segments
Unweighted shared DNA: 1,599 cM
Longest segment: 125 cM
99% uncle

Can you start to unravel this?

Comment: Did your father's mother have any known sisters, or your father's father any known brothers? https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/17712/10577 might start to be relevant.

Comment: @shoover  Yes to both.  My paternal grandmother had 3 sisters. and my paternal grandfather had several brothers. Unfortunately, this person will not consider any other options other than my dad.

Answer (score 5):

Half-sibling is not the only likely relationship at that cM range, it also includes aunt/uncle and niece/nephew.  So, depending on the age of the outside match, it could be either your uncle's half-brother, and therefore also your uncle; or your half-brother, and therefore your uncle's nephew.

https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4-beta

Answer (score 1):

One way for both you and your uncle to also be half siblings is that the same man (probably of your grandparents' generation) impregnated both your maternal grandmother and -- some decades later -- your mother.

(Note that I'm not commenting on the likelihood or the squick factor, but just how it can happen.)

Comment: Interesting theory.  Problem is it took my parents took  9 years to conceive me.  She was a Para 0 when I was born... Doctors can tell.

Comment: @MOMMAMIA9 **this is not a theory!!!**  Remember: "I'm not commenting on the likelihood ..., but just how it **can** happen."

Answer (score 0):

I ran this through DNA Painter's *What Are The Odds* tool. The only scenario that works is if the "outside male" is your half-sibling. In that case, your uncle is also his uncle, and the centimorgan results are consistent with those relationships. No incest or other weird relationships are necessary. I considered the possibility that the "outside male" is a half-sibling or full sibling to your uncle, but those didn't work. If “outside male” were your uncle’s half-brother, that would make him your half-uncle, but you share too much DNA for that relationship. Congratulations, you found a new half-brother! See the diagram I used [here](https://dnapainter.com/tools/probability/view/6fb4b85d4019fa1a).

Comment: Sounds  like a great tool, What I think I that my paternal grandfather impregnated the outsider's mom.  And as we know DNA doesn't always go 50-50.  Meaning my genetics are a bit more like my father's.  So that would make the outsider my Uncle 1/2 sibling and my half-uncle.  Also, the timing of conception and age difference between us leads me to that consideration  Many thanks for your input.

Comment: I believe that the outsider being your half uncle is ruled out. The world record maximum shared DNA for a half-aunt or uncle is 1315 cM.  You share 1655, way outside that range. If it is biologically possible that your father was also outsider's father, I think you better believe that scenario.  Unless, maybe, your family is Ashkenazi Jewish, or some other group that has a lot of endogamy (DNA shared among the group).